# Parsing HTML to array only returns one word

Tags: arrays, bash, parsing, awk, sed

I'm trying to parse some HTML subtitles into an array using Bash and html-xml-utils, and I've tried using a Lynx dump to pretty it up, but I had the same problem, because I can't get my `sed` to put more than one word at a time into the array.

Code:

```
    array=($(echo $PAGE |
       hxselect -i ".sub_info_container .sub_title" |
       sed -r 's/.*\">(.*)<\/a>.*/\1/' ))

echo $array
```

This gets piped into sed:

```
<div class="sub_title"><a class="sub_title" href="/link">Some Random Title.</a></div><div class="sub_title"><a class="sub_title" href="/link2">Another subtitle I want.</a>
```

Output of `echo $array`:

```
Some
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
Some Random Title
```

Without the punctuation would be nice, and the subtitles often have `?` or `!` instead of period, but it could work including punctuation too.

Things I've tried:

- Using Lynx to pretty up the code, then using `awk` to grab the elements
- A lot of different `sed` and `awk` methods of grabbing the text

Comment: remove the first set of parenthesis.

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but my code ended up separating spaces into separate items. The solution was the following code:

```
array=($(echo $PAGE |
       hxselect -i ".sub_info_container .sub_title" |
       lynx -stdin -dump | tr " " - ))
```

I used tr to turn the spaces into dashes, allowing it to be passed into the array. Taking off the extra parenthesis as everybody suggested actually removed the function of assigning the values into an array, as I stated was my intention. After the code completed I simply re-converted all the dashes back to spaces. It's not pretty but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s='<div class="sub_title"><a class="sub_title" href="/link">Some Random Title.</a></div><div class="sub_title"><a class="sub_title" href="/link2">Another subtitle I want.</a>'

array=$(echo "$s" | sed 's/<\/div><div /\n/' | sed -r 's/.*\">(.*)<\/a>.*/\1/g')

echo "$array"
```

I had to add a newline between the divs to match both. I'm not that good with sed and couldn't figure out how to do it without that.

Your main problem was with the extra parenthesis

```
array=($(echo .....))
```